# Jquery stop change event on manual trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bound a `change` event on "select box" which call when user changes select box value manually. But I want to stop change event call when we trigger change event by javascript like `$(element).trigger('change')`.
Please help

Comment: Why are you triggering the change event if you don't want to run the handler? What else is that supposed to do other than run the handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger method have another parameter (extraParameter ) and put your data. In handler check extraParameter to findout it is manually or with javascript code.

```
$(element).trigger('change',{'isTriggeredBySystem':true})
```

[jQuery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Very helpful for me.

Answer (score 7):

use the [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove an event listener.

```
$(element).off('change')
```